# Which is the best way to handle No internet connection in an Android App

Tags: android, user-experience

I work in Android development for more than 4 years and in all the projects I was involved, people always asked me which is the best way to handle No Internet connection use-case.
Checking it can be done in multiple ways, but I am still trying to decide what could be the best User experience ever.

One idea could be having an observer to check the internet connection and everytime it's lost, to show an activity over your current screen in order to inform the user that he lost connection. When the internet it's back, just call finish on that activity. But this blocks any interaction with the app.

Another one would be to personalize every screen of your app to show a customized No connection layout. But this can cost you a lot of work if you have more than 20 screens.

What do you think it's the best way to handle No internet connection in an Android app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs more on the UX stack exchange rather than here (at least judging by the current answer set)

Comment: it really depends on your app and what the goal of your app is, which is why i agree with @Jeeter that it's off-topic and should be in the UX stack exchange (if anywhere)  but it could be entirely too broad as it is.

Comment: @Jeeter Oh, yes, you are right. Sorry for that. I should move it there, but still there are some good answers. What should I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [material.io](https://material.io/design/communication/offline-states.html#offline-functionality) you can show a `cardview` with your desired views informing the user of the current network state. This way, a user is not blocked from interacting with the app. [image]

Comment: I think this is one of the best solutions for many types of apps. Not blocking the UI (this means having an offline behaviour for your app) and can be easily included in all the layouts. Maybe having a Base Activity/Fragment class in order to manage the No internet connection case in one place. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would say **Snackbar**. It looks good, doesn't block UI, provides actions (unlike Toast) that are not forced on user (unlike Activity and Dialog) as well and requires only 1 line of code. As simple as that.

**Activity** - Bad Option, blocks UI, requires input from user, can be annoying, comes with boilerplate
**Toast**    - Looks "satisfactory" but can't specify actions
**Dialog**   - Makes User action *mandatory* to dismiss, doesn't look as good

For Snackbar, there is only one con that I can think of, it works best with `CoordinatorLayout` , like moving layout up instead of overlapping it. Other than that, it fits the bill.

TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY(from experience)

Answer (score 4):

There is no "best way" to handle not having an internet connection. It depends on various different aspects and it should be up to your designer and/or business rules.

Consider this :

1. If you're making an app for tracking the live locations of users as
   a way of providing an emergency service if something goes wrong
   (checking if they've been in a car accident, etc) then connection
   becomes exponentially more important. Here, you definitely DO want to make the user aware that there's no connection, you probably will end up blocking the UI from the user until they are connected again or you will have to provide limited functionality, etc.
2. If you're working on an app which occasionally (think, every hour, 2 hours, etc) gets you more
   information (like a weather app) is internet connectivity really
   THAT important ? you can show dialogs or retries or just show the last data you had available too, but it's really not of vital importance (for the average weather app) to get live data every single time you use it (again, depends on the situation, it could be)

There's no single solution for all scenario's. losing connectivity is not AS FATAL or important for all apps and that's why this question is too broad.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. So it depends from one case to another, from one app to another.

Comment: yes, user experience and user interface design is always dependent on the type of app and various other aspects, there's no single solution which works for everything.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Still, there can be one which can cover multiple cases - see the answer from Taseer Ahmad. Using a cardview like that can be a good compromise. But still the app needs to have a defined behavior for offline usage. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I implemented this functionality without using any extra activity or toast or dialog.So here goes the idea.Actually I am retrieving data from server and displaying in the listView.If  there is no internet,i would display the user as below.
[image]

If there is internet, i would display the data as below
[image]

So,how did I make it?
Just use the concept of visibilities.Firstly by default,I made the visibility of listview to gone and that Internet image and below text visible.If there is  internet,I just changed the image and text visibility to gone and listview as visible.Do this accordingly to your requirements.Any doubts? Feel free to comment.